# Why is my python code returning a syntax error?

Tags: python, syntax

I'm new to python and I've been trying to improve by creating some practice code.

```
user_number = input('Enter in the number you want the factorial of: ')
print(str(user_number) + '! is equal to ' + str(factorial(int(user_number))))
```

I've already defined the factorial function earlier in my code and the problem seems to be coming from these two lines. Is there a syntax error which I don't see??

Comment: could you inculde the factorial function in your post

Comment: What happens when you replace the `input` statement with a simple assignment?  Remember the "minimal" part.

Comment: You need to provide the error string which you are getting as well. Also assuming your factorial function works, and you input an integer whose factorial doesn't overflow, these two lines should work

Comment: If you appear to be getting a syntax error at the first of the two lines you present, it is very likely that the error is in the line above. The interpreter tells you at exactly what line and character it ran into a problem. But sometimes it continues trying to make sense of your code and only discovers in the next line that something is wrong with the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function in Python 2 evaluates the user input as Python code rather than taking it literally. You should use `raw_input` instead in Python 2:

```
user_number = raw_input('Enter in the number you want the factorial of: ')
```

Comment: In Python 2.7 using `input` in this situation will not normally give a syntax error. If you type a number it will accept the number. If you type an invalid expression like `2 + 3 (` you *will* get a syntax error, but only at runtime and in response to the input. If you type a string without enclosing quotes you will usually get a NameError because the string can't be interpreted as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Python 3 since your print statement is a function call. When I tried your code using

```
import math
```

then this line instead:

```
print(str(user_number) + '! is equal to ' + str(math.factorial(int(user_number))))
```

the result was:

```
10! is equal to 3628800
```

I entered a 10 as the value. 
Perhaps the issue is in your factorial function. Hard to know unless you post that as well.

Answer (score 0):

The below code works for me. I doubt that there may be a problem in your factorial function.

```
def factorial(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return n * factorial(n-1)

user_number = input('Enter in the number you want the factorial of: ')
print(str(user_number) + '! is equal to ' + str(factorial(int(user_number))))
```